# Single Munin server to host multiple projects

Tags: nginx, munin, fcgi

We have multiple projects to be monitored with Munin, and naturally we have a separate Munin server for each project.

But now that we're using Munin 2.0 + Nginx/fcgi and it's scalable with many munin-nodes, I'm thinking if it's possible to co-host all projects with a single Munin server.

Requirements are:

- Access control: an owner of a project can't view another project's munin graphs
- Maintainability: Single binary update on the server

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from Adrien "ze" Urban on the IRC channel - it's possible, and there's documentation for that, written by him. Munin sure has a cool community!

http://munin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example/webserver/nginx.html#authentication-and-group-access

Comment: Hi!

interesting post! I've checked the link you provided and I don't understand how nginx helps to the feature of the "owner of graph project can't view graps of other projects".

I mean, once you have entered user and password, you can change links and navigate inside munin, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, there is a hosted version of munin that can provide this functionality for you. http://hostedmunin.com/

(full disclosure; I'm affiliated with this service)